# Asp.net C# DataBase Insertion Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010

Am running a simple application on asp.net that is taking input from text boxes on various pages and then on the last page am using the insertion method through adapters. when i use dummy inputs like hjihi for the text boxes am not getting an exception. how ever when i use proper inputs for fields i get this whole page of horridly error. Searched it but cudn't get a proper answer.

```
Server Error in '/Job Portal10' Application.

String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Description:`An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.`

`Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: String or binary data would be truncated.`
The statement has been terminated.

Source Error:

```
Line 6127:            }
Line 6128:            try {
Line 6129:          int returnValue =    this.Adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
Line 6130:                return returnValue;
Line 6131:            }
```

`Source File: c:\Users\Haris Riaz\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\job portal10\a1906c7c\e3e5272e\App_Code.6jqq8vva.1.cs    Line: 6129`

`Stack Trace: 
    [SqlException (0x80131904): String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +2030802
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +5009584
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() +234
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +2275
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +215
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async) +987
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result) +162
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe) +178
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +137
   DataSet1TableAdapters.Emp_UpdateTableAdapter.Insert(String Title, String First_Name, String Last_Name, String F_First_Name, String F_Last_Name, String Gender, String Nationality, String Maritial_Status, String DOB, String CNIC, String Domicile, String Dependents, String Qualification_10Years, String Board_10_Years_Edu, String Completion_10_years, String Percmarks_10_Years, String Division_10_Years, String Qualification_12_years, String Board_12_years_Edu, String Completion_12_years, String Percmarks_12_Years, String Division_12_years, String Qualification_16_years, String Board_16_years_Edu, String Completion_16_years, String Percmarks_16_Years, String Division_16_years, String Qualification_18_years, String Board_18_years_Edu, String Completion_18_years, String Percmarks_18_Years, String Division_18_years, String Qualification_21_years, String Board_21_years_Edu, String Completion_21_years, String Percmarks_21_Years, String Division_21_years, String exp_1_Organization, String Designation_1, String Duration_From_1_1, String Duration_From_1_2, String Address_1, String Contact_1, String Supervisor_1, String Jobreason_1, String StartingSalary_1, String EndingSalary_1, String exp_2_Organization, String Designation_2, String Duration_From_2_1, String Duration_From_2_2, String Address_2, String Contact_2, String Supervisor_2, String Jobreason_2, String StartingSalary_2, String EndingSalary_2, String exp_3_Organization, String Designation_3, String Duration_From_3_1, String Duration_From_3_2, String Address_3, String Contact_3, String Supervisor_3, String Jobreason_3, String StartingSalary_3, String EndingSalary_3, String Permanent_Address, String Current_Address, String Permanent_City, String Current_City, String Permanent_Country, String Phone_Number, String Mobile_Number, String Email_Address, String Fax, String Ref_Name_1, String Ref_Designation_1, String Ref_Org_1, String Ref_Email_1, String Ref_Add_1, String Ref_Mobile_1, String Ref_Name_2, String Ref_Designation_2, String Ref_Org_2, String Ref_Email_2, String Ref_Add_2, String Ref_Mobile_2, String Ref_Name_3, String Ref_Designation_3, String Ref_Org_3, String Ref_Email_3, String Ref_Add_3, String Ref_Mobile_3) in c:\Users\Haris Riaz\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\job portal10\a1906c7c\e3e5272e\App_Code.6jqq8vva.1.cs:6129
   UpdateProfile.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Haris Riaz\Desktop\apna kaam\Job Portal10\UpdateProfile_References.aspx.cs:58
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +118
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +112
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563`

Here is my c# i used with my button

```
public partial class UpdateProfile : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    DatabaseConnect DB = new DatabaseConnect();
    DataSet1TableAdapters.Emp_UpdateTableAdapter td = new   DataSet1TableAdapters.Emp_UpdateTableAdapter();

static public String ref_name_1;
static public String ref_designation_1;
static public String ref_org_1;
static public String ref_email_1;
static public String ref_add_1;
static public String ref_mobile_1;
static public String ref_name_2;
static public String ref_designation_2;
static public String ref_org_2;
static public String ref_email_2;
static public String ref_add_2;
static public String ref_mobile_2;
static public String ref_name_3;
static public String ref_designation_3;
static public String ref_org_3;
static public String ref_email_3;
static public String ref_add_3;
static public String ref_mobile_3;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ref_name_1 = TextBox10.Text;
    ref_designation_1 = TextBox11.Text;
    ref_org_1 = TextBox12.Text;
    ref_email_1 = TextBox13.Text;
    ref_add_1 = TextBox14.Text;
    ref_mobile_1 = TextBox28.Text;
    ref_name_2 = TextBox16.Text;
    ref_designation_2 = TextBox17.Text;
    ref_org_2 = TextBox18.Text;
    ref_email_2 = TextBox19.Text;
    ref_add_2 = TextBox20.Text;
    ref_mobile_2 = TextBox29.Text;
    ref_name_3 = TextBox22.Text;
    ref_designation_3 = TextBox23.Text;
    ref_org_3 = TextBox24.Text;
    ref_email_3 = TextBox25.Text;
    ref_add_3 = TextBox26.Text;
    ref_mobile_3 = TextBox30.Text;

    td.Insert(Session["Titl"].ToString(),
     Session["First_Name"].ToString(), 
     Session["Last_Name"].ToString(),
     Session["F_First_Name"].ToString(),
     Session["F_Last_Name"].ToString(),
     Session["Gender"].ToString(),
     Session["Nationality"].ToString(),
     Session["Maritial_Status"].ToString(),
     Session["DOB"].ToString(),
     Session["CNIC"].ToString(),
     Session["Domicile"].ToString(),
     Session["Dependents"].ToString(),
     Session["Qualification_10Years"].ToString(),
     Session["Board_10_Years_Edu"].ToString(), 
     Session["Completion_10_years"].ToString(),
     Session["Percmarks_10_Years"].ToString(),
     Session["Division_10_Years"].ToString(), 
     Session["Qualification_12Years"].ToString(),
     Session["Board_12_Years_Edu"].ToString(), 
     Session["Completion_12_years"].ToString(),
     Session["Percmarks_12_Years"].ToString(), 
     Session["Division_12_Years"].ToString(), 
     Session["Qualification_16Years"].ToString(), 
     Session["Board_16_Years_Edu"].ToString(),
     Session["Completion_16_years"].ToString(),
     Session["Percmarks_16_Years"].ToString(),null, 
     Session["Qualification_18Years"].ToString(), 
     Session["Board_18_Years_Edu"].ToString(),
     Session["Completion_18_years"].ToString(),
     Session["Percmarks_18_Years"].ToString(),null, 
     Session["Qualification_21Years"].ToString(),
     Session["Board_21_Years_Edu"].ToString(),
     Session["Completion_21_years"].ToString(), 
     Session["Percmarks_21_Years"].ToString(),null, 
     Session["exp_1_Organization"].ToString(),
     Session["Designation_1"].ToString(),
     Session["Duration_from_1_1"].ToString(),
     Session["Duration_from_1_2"].ToString(),
     Session["address_1"].ToString(),
     Session["contact_1"].ToString(),
     Session["supervisor_1"].ToString(),
     Session["job_reason_1"].ToString(),
     Session["starting_salary_1"].ToString(),
     Session["ending_salary_1"].ToString(),
     Session[" exp_2_Organization"].ToString(),
    Session[" Designation_2"].ToString(),
    Session[" Duration_from_2_1"].ToString(),
    Session[" Duration_from_2_2"].ToString(),
    Session[" address_2"].ToString(),
    Session[" contact_2"].ToString(),
    Session[" supervisor_2"].ToString(),
    Session[" job_reason_2"].ToString(),
    Session[" starting_salary_2"].ToString(),
    Session[" ending_salary_2"].ToString(),
    Session[" exp_3_Organization"].ToString(),
    Session[" Designation_3"].ToString(),
    Session[" Duration_from_3_1"].ToString(),
    Session[" Duration_from_3_2"].ToString(),
    Session[" address_3"].ToString(),
    Session[" contact_3"].ToString(),
    Session[" supervisor_3"].ToString(),
    Session[" job_reason_3"].ToString(),
    Session[" starting_salary_3"].ToString(),
    Session[" ending_salary_3"].ToString(),
    Session["permanent_address"].ToString(),
    Session["current_address"].ToString(),
    Session["permanent_city"].ToString(),
    Session["current_city"].ToString(),
    Session["permanent_country"].ToString(),
    Session["phone_number"].ToString(),
    Session["mobile_number"].ToString(),
    Session["email_address"].ToString(),
    Session["fax"].ToString(),
    ref_name_1,
     ref_designation_1,
     ref_org_1,
     ref_email_1,
     ref_add_1,
     ref_mobile_1,
     ref_name_2,
     ref_designation_2,
     ref_org_2,
     ref_email_2,
     ref_add_2,
     ref_mobile_2,
     ref_name_3,
     ref_designation_3,
     ref_org_3,
     ref_email_3,
     ref_add_3,
     ref_mobile_3);


}
```

}

Comment: ` int returnValue = this.Adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); ` = is missing in your statement

Comment: Waqar bhai can you please explain a bit more??

Comment: oh yes u have the = sign i missed it while typing the question here. That is not the problem! kindly check it! There is something else!

Comment: executenoequery returns an integer. You create a variable retrunValue but you are not assigning it correctly. It should be look like this  int returnValue = this.Adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: let me edit my question and post it exactly as i got the error!

Comment: the error seems to present in your query. Share the insert query.

Comment: here is the code behind the button. i made a dataset used the table adapter to create built in insert query! See the question edited for code at the bottom!

Comment: check the below answer he is right, the problem occurred when you insert data more then you specified in the database

Comment: now mark the walther answer as your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: String or
>   binary data would be truncated.

This error indicates you're trying to insert some data, that is longer/larger than a specified column type. A simple example: you've specified a column of a type varchar(200), but you're trying to insert a string of length 500.

To prevent exceptions like this, I'd suggest to implement some kind of a client-side (+ server-side, of course) validation of inputted data.

Comment: may be you are right coz when i inserted dummy values in my form like bnmb consisting of only 4 characters i did not get this exception!

Comment: @HarisRiaz, well, I've seen this exception too many times for my taste to be wrong about its meaning ;)

Comment: @HarisRiaz, I'm glad :)) If it helped you, you may consider marking the answer, so other people with similar problem can easily find the solution ;)